# Cant print out values from my array in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, variables, printing, instance

How do i print out my values using only "Puts recipe.summary? ive looped through them in "instructions" and "ingredients" but none of it shows when i "Puts recipe.summary".

Maybe im looping through it incorrectly?
Here is my code.

```
  class Ingredient
  attr_reader :quantity, :unit, :name, :summary 
  def initialize (quantity,unit,name)
    @quantity = quantity
    @unit = unit
    @name = name
    @summary= summary
  end

  def summary
    "#{quantity} #{unit} #{name}"
  end
end




class Recipe
  attr_reader :name, :instructions,:ingredients

  def initialize(name,instructions,ingredient)
    @name = name
    @instructions = instructions
    @ingredient = ingredient
  end

  def instructions
 @instructions= instructions.each do |instruction|
   puts instruction
  end
end

  def ingredients

    @ingredients = ingredients.each do |ingredient|
      puts ingredient
    end


  def summary
    @summary
    puts "Name: #{name}"
    puts "#{ingredients}"
  end
end
end

# ingredient = Ingredient.new(47.0, "lb(s)", "Brussels Sprouts")
# puts ingredient.summary

name = "Roasted Brussels Sprouts"

instructions = [
   "Preheat oven to 400 degrees F.",
   "Cut off the brown ends of the Brussels sprouts.",
   "Pull off any yellow outer leaves.",
   "Mix them in a bowl with the olive oil, salt and pepper.",
   "Pour them on a sheet pan and roast for 35 to 40 minutes.",
   "They should be until crisp on the outside and tender on the inside.",
   "Shake the pan from time to time to brown the sprouts evenly.",
   "Sprinkle with more kosher salt ( I like these salty like French fries).",
   "Serve and enjoy!"
 ]

ingredients = [
  Ingredient.new(1.5, "lb(s)", "Brussels sprouts"),
  Ingredient.new(3.0, "tbspn(s)", "Good olive oil"),
  Ingredient.new(0.75, "tspn(s)", "Kosher salt"),
  Ingredient.new(0.5, "tspn(s)", "Freshly ground black pepper")
]


recipe = Recipe.new(name, instructions, ingredients)
puts recipe.summary
```

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". Try reducing your code to the bare minimum that duplicates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `puts` after trying to return @summary.
Technically the result of `puts "#{ingredients}"` is what is returned, which is probably nothing.
Move the `puts` above.

```
def summary
    puts "Name: #{name}"
    puts "#{ingredients}"
    @summary
end
```

Comment: It still doesnt print anything after that, though i see what your saying.

Answer (score 1):

The Recipe object doesn't have a `summary` method because you didn't pay attention to your nesting:

```
  def ingredients

    @ingredients = ingredients.each do |ingredient|
      puts ingredient
    end


  def summary
    @summary
    puts "Name: #{name}"
    puts "#{ingredients}"
  end
end
```

Move the `summary` method outside the `ingredients` method.

`@summary` inside the `summary` method doesn't do any so Ruby will throw that away.

You are causing loops by confusing Ruby with method names that are generated with `attr_reader` and calling them from inside methods with the same names, such as:

```
attr_reader :name, :instructions,:ingredients

...

  def instructions
   @instructions= instructions.each do |instruction|
   puts instruction
  end
```

You'll get `SystemStackError: stack level too deep` when running that code.

I'd recommend working through tutorials on writing Ruby code, using an editor that automatically handles indentation or that makes it easy to reformat/indent, and installing a code analyzer like Rubocop and using it religiously.